# Server software for handling multiple mp3/ogg streams

Tags: android, streaming, icecast

I'm looking for advice regarding an aspect of a project I'm working on.

I'm developing a demo android app for a not-for-profit that specialises in services for the vision impaired. The plan is, among other things, the app will enable users to stream this organization's specialised audiobooks.

For the sake of demo'ing/development I need to establish some sort of server which will, pending a request from a device running the app:

- directly transfer certain xml/html index files to the android phone (no streaming necessary)
- stream .ogg and .mp3 audio files to the device
- serve more than one client device at a time
- start a stream from a specific point within an mp3/ogg file, pending a request from the phone app

I've had a look at Icecast as an mp3/ogg streaming solution, but my knowledge of servers is a bit limited (I've only ever done some basic work in Flask). Would I need to run this in tandem with something that can generically serve files / handle requests?

I'm basically just looking for a good solution/tool to implement this is. The server side doesn't need to be completely fleshed out, just fit the bill above, as my focus is developing the phone app side for now. For the sake of a demo, something straightforward / well documented would suit best.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a special server for this.  Any HTTP server that supports range requests will be fine.  This includes Nginx, Apache, etc.  There is no need to spoon-feed clients media data from the server.  This streaming and buffering aspect is handled automatically on the client, through TCP window size and outright closing the connection and connecting again later as-needed.

Icecast is meant for radio-style streams where everyone listening hears the same thing at roughly the same time.  Since that's not an aspect you want, stick to any normal HTTP server.

Comment: Hi. Sorry I've not been available for a while due to work. Can you point me to an example / source-code where someone has done this. I was trying to look up a good starting point, and immediately ran into a pseudo-dissenting opinion here: [link](https://serverfault.com/questions/233068/can-you-stream-an-mp3-file-with-nginx).

Comment: @user3577502 That answer you linked to is totally wrong.  And, there is no example or source code because you don't need to do anything extra.  You literally just install Nginx, or whatever webserver you want to use for all your other web assets.